# Element propagation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, element

I've created a element populator, which takes certain elements, wraps them in HTML tags and appends them to a container. The problem I have, which is more of nuisance if anything, is for every image to be loaded it has to be input automatically. Is there a way to retrieve all images from a folder and load them into an array?

I have this code, which works, but with manual input:

```
    $(window).on('load', function () {

    var gallery = document.getElementById("grid");
    var images = [
        "./imgs/galeria/0.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/1.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/2.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/3.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/4.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/7.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/6.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/5.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/8.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/9.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/10.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/11.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/12.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/13.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/14.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/15.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/16.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/17.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/18.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/19.jpg",
        "./imgs/galeria/20.jpg"
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

        var thumbnailWrapper = document.createElement("div");

        thumbnailWrapper.className = "thumbnail-wrapper";

        var thumbnail = document.createElement("div");

        thumbnail.className = "thumbnail";

        thumbnail.dataset.source = "./imgs/galeria/" + i + ".jpg";

        thumbnailWrapper.appendChild(thumbnail);

        gallery.appendChild(thumbnailWrapper);
    }

    var thumb = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail');
    // console.log(thumb);

    for (j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
        // $(thumb[j]).attr('src', images[j]);
        $(thumb[j]).css('background-image', 'url(./imgs/galeria/thumbs/' + j + 'tbm.jpg)');
        // console.log(j);
        // console.log(images[j]);
    }
```

You can see the script in action in this [website](http://mingus.pt/vianense/) I made in the "galeria" section.

EDIT: maybe something with ajax? I wanted to keep php out of the equation
EDIT2: I would like to make it with ajax, and this is now the correct code

Comment: I don't see where you use AJAX. Also, why do you use `document.write`, `document.getElementsByClassName` and jQuery at the same time?

Comment: function require(path) but in the function body "jspath" - WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use client-side JavaScript to scan a folder on a server. If you don't know what files the folder contains, then AJAX alone doesn't even work.

You have to use server-side code, such as PHP, to find all the files in the folder, and them deliver them somehow to the client. That is the only way I see.

This approach could work:

```php
$images = glob('imgs/galeria/*.jpg');

echo '<div id="grid">';

foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
  echo '<div class="thumbnail-wrapper">';
  echo '<div 
    class="thumbnail" 
    data-source="' . $image . '"
    style="background-image: url(imgs/galeria/thumbs/' . $key . 'tbm.jpg)"
    ></div>';
  echo '</div>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

I hope this works like your JavaScript code does.

Comment: the folder only contains images, all .jpgs and ordered, numeric file names

Comment: OK, but still the best solution is server-side code. Otherwise, you'd have to make requests, every time increasing the number, until there server sends a 404. That would be very ugly.

Comment: so.. php... can you maybe help me out?

Comment: In the place where you currently have your `div` element with the id `grid`. The PHP code puts the inner divs in the container before the page is delivered, instead of populating the container dynamically with JavaScript.